# IntelliJ maven lifecycle - can I modify "Basic Tasks Only" list?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-lifecycle

In the IntelliJ *Maven Projects* tree-view pane, you can see the Lifecycle tasks for all of the maven modules.

By default, these show "Basic Tasks Only". I can untick this, but then I see everything.....

Is it possible to add just one task (integration-test) to the "Basic Tasks Only" list?

i.e. can the IntelliJ Maven Integration plugin be configured?

Or can I write my own plugin to configure this at runtime?

Any tips appreciated. IntelliJ 12.1.4.

Comment: I don't think it is possible, but I'm not sure that it really makes sense. You will sometimes have the need to show all the phases of the lifecycle, but this is usually followed by the creation of a run configuration based on these phases, so that you will always use the run configuration once it is created.

Comment: True, run configurations are possible, however I tend to prefer the maven modules / lifecycle tree view, since I find it more convenient, thus the question.

Comment: Well then I can just say that the Maven plugin is not configurable like this, but of course you could modify it to have a more flexible configuration when showing the lifecycle phases. It is in the Community Edition, so code is available, and patches are, as far as I know, always welcome by JetBrains.

Comment: @Tome ok, thanks mate. If you want to write your comment as an answer I'm happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven plugin is not configurable like this, it is either showing only basic phases or full lifecycle.
A typical workaround for your use case would be to create a Maven run configuration based on the phase you want to launch.
If you really want to fine grain the visible phases inside the Maven tool window, you would have to modify the IntelliJ Community Edition, whose code is available, patches are always welcome by JetBrains.